# Applying a CSS style to an HTML table

Tags: html, css, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but this question relates to HTML5 from within a Windows 8 app.

I have the following input form:

```
<div class="input-form">
    <form id="myData" >
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Data1</td>
                <td><input type="text" title="data1" id="data1" value="test" required /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data2</td>                            
                <td>
                    <div>
                       <input type="text" title="data2" id="data2" />
                       <button id="lookup">...</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
...
```

The idea being that the user clicks the ellipses and something happens (to help them enter the data).  This works okay, however, in a Windows 8 app, you have to cater for snapped mode.  So here's my CSS styling to deal with that so far:

```
@media screen and (-ms-view-state: snapped) {
.homepage section[role=main] {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.input-form {
    width:320px;        
}
```

What this gives me is just the second column of the table - which is fine, but for the field with the ellipses, I want to be able to see the ellipses, too.  I've tried various things: setting the width on the two fields, setting the table width, but whatever I do it doesn't seem to make a difference.

I'm aware that someone is going to tell me that using a table is a bad thing, and I'll be condemned to the seventh circle of hell or something; but before I did use a table I tried various other approaches, none of which gave me the table effect that I wanted.

So my question is, how can I style the table; or, if that isn't possible, how can I format my HTML so that it appears as a table?

EDIT:

Just to clarify that I have tried other methods:

```
<div class="input-form">                    
    <form id="mailData" >
        <div id="input-left">
            <div>Data1</div>
            <div>Data2</div>
        </div>

        <div id="input-centre">
            <div><input type="text" title="data1" id="data1" value="test" required /></div>
            <input type="text" title="data2" id="data2" />                                                                    
        </div>

        <div id="input-right">
            <div></div>
            <button id="lookup">...</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And the styling that that:

```
.input-form {    
margin-left:320px;
display:-ms-grid;
-ms-grid-rows:1fr;
-ms-grid-columns:auto auto auto;
height:100%;
}

#input-left {
-ms-grid-column: 1;
}

#input-centre {
-ms-grid-column: 2;
}

#input-right {
-ms-grid-column: 3;
}
```

This just displays the form with Data1, Data2 labels followed beneath by the input boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTH.

sample html:

```
<div class="inputs form">
    <div class="property data1">
        <h2 class="caption">Data1</h2>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter value here" required="required"/>
    </div>
    <div class="property data2">
        <h2 class="caption">Data2</h2>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter value here" />
        <button type="button">...</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

sample css:

```
.inputs.form
{
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
}

.inputs.form .property
{
    display: -ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: auto auto auto;
}

    .inputs.form .property .caption
    {
        -ms-grid-row-align: center;
        padding: 0 20px 0 0;
    }

    .inputs.form .property input
    {
        -ms-grid-column: 2;
    }

    .inputs.form .property button
    {
        -ms-grid-column: 3;
        min-width: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of a place where using Blend for Visual Studio would probably make your life easier. Blend allows you to work with the elements on your page and the CSS styles that apply to them in a visual fashion, so you can see immediately what the impact of a given rule is. Blend also supports (through the Device pane) viewing your content in any of the 4 defined view states, including snapped view, so you can immediately tell whether your rules are doing what you want them to do.

Here's some [documentation for designing HTML apps in Blend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj155209.aspx) to help get you started.

While I won't consign you to any circle of hell for using tables (using tables for layout tends to be self-punishing anyway), I would recommend that you take a look at the [CSS3 Grid layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh673533.aspx) and [CSS3 Flexible Box layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453474.aspx) documentation, which provide a couple of good alternatives to the use of table elements for layout.

There's also a [Quickstart on defining app layouts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj150600.aspx) that you might find helpful.

For more information on Windows Store app development, register for [App Builder](http://bit.ly/gd30tolaunch).

Comment: I actually am using blend. I find it to be less helpful with HTML / CSS than it is with XAML regarding view states.  I'm a little confused on your answer, are you saying it is possible to style a table, or it is not, or that it is not?

Comment: It is possible to style a table, sure. But using CSS Grid or CSS Flexbox layouts will work better.

Comment: Okay, so how would I style the table in my question to make sure that both the field and the button are visible?

Comment: Hard to say, given that you've not included either the full relevant markup, nor the base styles for the page. But part of the challenge that you're facing is that you're starting from a layout that assumes a label and input field side-by-side, which is generally not how snapped view works. FWIW, if I plug your markup and styles into a new navigation project in Blend, it works as expected for me, that is, the button automatically wraps to the next line when I snap the app. Perhaps there's something in your CSS that isn't shown that's preventing this behavior?

Comment: I've edited my question.  The reason I ended up with a table was that I couldn't get the -ms-grid to work.  Maybe I'm asking the wrong question :-)